# How to optimise very simple query with subquery that only needs to execute once

Tags: mysql, performance, subquery, count, query-performance

```
SELECT products_id, products_model, products_iban_no, products_allocation_number FROM products WHERE products_model IN (SELECT products_model FROM products GROUP BY products_model HAVING COUNT(products_model) > 1)
```

For whatever reason, it would seem that the subquery is being run for each product. I only need it to be run once really - and would have thought that mysql would intelligently realise this. Otherwise I would have written it like

```
SELECT products_id, products_model, products_iban_no, products_allocation_number FROM products AS a WHERE (SELECT COUNT(products_model) FROM products AS b WHERE a.products_model = b.products_model GROUP BY products_model) > 1
```

But bizzarely - the second query is actually faster by a factor of precisely 3 (31 seconds as opposed to 1 minute 33 seconds), despite being a "foreach" way of thinking rather than "set theory" way of thinking. I thought the latter was supposed to be much quicker? Clearly I have written the first query incorrectly - but how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with a join?

```
SELECT a.products_id, a.products_model, a.products_iban_no
     , a.products_allocation_number
FROM products a
JOIN (
    SELECT products_model
    FROM products
    GROUP BY products_model
    HAVING COUNT(products_model) > 1
) as b
    on a.products_model = b.products_model
```

Comment: This works great, thank you. Is there any particular reason it is quicker or is it an implementation thing?

Comment: Implementation thing, in theory the DBMS should be able  to process your statement just as good as mine, in practice joins often works better than in predicates (especially true for mysql).